# Using the Law Quadratic Residues

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm looking to find if $\bigg(\frac{1210}{41}\bigg)$ so is 1210 a quadratic residue modulo 41.

So I have $\bigg(\frac{1210}{41}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{21}{41}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{3}{41}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{7}{41}\bigg)$

Taking the question in parts i get $\bigg(\frac{3}{41}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{41}{3}\bigg)=(-1)^{20}=1 \rightarrow \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)=-1$

Using this i then have $-\bigg(\frac{7}{41}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{7}{41}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{41}{7}\bigg)=(-1)^{60}=1 \rightarrow -\bigg(\frac{41}{7}\bigg)=-\bigg(\frac{6}{7}\bigg)=1$

So i get -1 therefore 1210 is not a Quadratic Residue modulo 41.
Is this the correct answer for this question and correct method?

Comment: Why did you write $\left(\frac{3}{41}\right)\left(\frac{41}{3}\right) = \ldots$? Don't you just want to compute $\left(\frac{3}{41}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{7}{41}\right)$?

Comment: @JohnMartin Quadratic residue Law in our lecture notes it let p and q be odd primes.Then $(\frac{p}{q})(\frac{q}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}$ thats how i get that part.

Comment: Do you know quadratic reciprocity? See Joanpemo's answer below. His answer is what I was getting at...

Comment: Observe that if $\;p=1\pmod4\;$ *or* $\;q=1\pmod 4\;$ you get $$\left(\frac pq\right)=\left(\frac qp\right)$$ Using this, which is QR, you an deal with much lower primes.

Comment: Your last calculation is wrong, $(6/7) = -1$, not $+1$.

Comment: I'm using the formula i have from my lecture notes, don't understand the law in any depth @JohnMartin but just check on an online calculator and it gives me -1, so 1210 isnt a quadratic residue. if i was to use the answer below that would give me 1 and that would be a quadratic residue in that case?

Comment: @ErickWong I know it is 1, but the - on the outside of the bracket them makes it a -1

Comment: @JohnMartin Writing $\left(\frac{3}{41}\right)\left(\frac{41}{3}\right)$ is a common way to express quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: @LUC No, I mean it is $-1$.  The $-$ on the outside makes it $+1$.  Also note that $12^2 \equiv 21 \pmod{41}$, so $21$ really is a QR.

Comment: @ErickWong Indeed it is. I was just trying to get a handle on where the OP is at. What he writes tells you that the product of the reciprocals is 1 or -1, but it doesn't necessarily tell you which is which (in the case of -1). For instance, as you point out above.

Comment: @ErickWong, yeah sorry i think i see my mistake so it in fact should be 1, and therefore is a quadratic residue?

Comment: @LUC Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac3{41}\right)=\left(\frac{41}3\right)=\left(\frac23\right)=-1$$

$$\left(\frac7{41}\right)=\left(\frac{41}7\right)=\left(\frac{-1}7\right)=-1$$